# Strange message after su

Tags: ubuntu, root, su

After performing the regular update of my Ubuntu 10.04.1, and a reboot (because kernel update), I opened a terminal window and entered

```
  $ su -
  Password: 

  su: Authentication failure
  $
  $ su -
  Password: 
  Added user root.

  #
```

(First I entered a wrong password (I think))
I do that all the time but this is the first time I get `Added user root`.

Does somebody know from where does this message come? Should I worry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message probably comes from PAM. Though I can't think of any module that would add a user account just like that. You may want to post `/etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/pam.d/common-*`.

Check `/etc/passwd`, look for files starting with passwd in /etc. If there aren't any additional ones (especially with dpkg or similar ending) and passwd file doesn't list suspicious users (or more than one user with UID 0) then I think you shouldn't worry.

Comment: The `pam.d` setup is untouched (by me). Did a `grep Added /etc/pam.d/*`, result nothing.

Comment: The "added user X" message would be compiled in to a pam module, not written in `/etc/pam.d`

Comment: Thanks. Please see the message I added below (in the other answer).

Answer (score 1):

change root password to temporary

Console 1:

```
$ LC_ALL=C su -
Password:
```

Console2:

```
# strace -fp `pgrep ^su$` 2> ~/strace
```

Console1:

```
Enter password and then $ exit
```

Then mail ~/strace to bindbn at gmail.com

Comment: <code>pam_smbpasswd.so</code> module? Please, post the files I asked you to, it is safe to do. I don't have a Ubuntu 10.04 machine avaiable.